# Pointing Android Studio to specific cmake version

Tags: android-studio, cmake, ninja

I use Android Studio 4.0.1
In my project, my local.properties has the following properties:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
ndk.dir=c\:\\yyy\\tools\\android-ndk-r19c
cmake.dir=c\:\\zzz\\cmake-3.17.0-win64-x64
```

Despite this, I get a compilation error when I Build -> Rebuild project or Clean project because my CMakeLists.txt begins with `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.3)` and Android Studio uses the CMake included in the Android Studio folder instead of the one I point to in cmake.dir:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (cmake_minimum_required):
CMake 3.14.3 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.10.2
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/E2e/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/x86/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
FAILED: build.ninja
ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe -HC:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\E2e\app\src\main\cpp -BC:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\E2e\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\x86
```

What am I missing for AS to pick up the cmake 3.17 I already installed when I select Rebuild Project or Clean Project?

Notes:

- The directory I point to with cmake.dir is valid and being read by AS.  If I introduce a typo in the path, AS complains about it.
- This problem only occurs when I do Build --> Rebuild project or Clean project.  If instead I do Build --> Make project, then AS will pick up the cmake version that I point to in local.properties

Answer (score 2):

`Clean Project` worked again after deleting `.cxx` folder

Comment: It does, but I am still unclear why the correct version of cmake isn't necessarily used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about **Android Studio**, but you could try editing the project's **build.gradle** :

```
android {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.24.1'
        }
    }
}
```

.... and **CMakeLists.txt** :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24.1)
```